# When entering an incorrect password three times. I want a program that will not open until after two days

Tags: vb.net-2010

When entering an incorrect password three times. I want a program that will not open until after two or three days.

```
If Now. Day. To String("d") Mod 2 = 0 Then
           Form2.Show()
       End If
try
if (DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Settings.Default.VIPVAL, Date And Time.Now) >= 2)
```

Comment: I advise you to take the [tour], to visit the [help], to read [ask] and to learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).